# make a select box readonly- shows the contents but not able to change any options

Tags: jquery, select, find

i have a select box full of values. How to do this condition in jquery:-

- search for a select val in the select boxes
- then remove all the other , except the one which has the current val.

I tried with the following, but it can be added only new value. Please help

```js
$('.selectBox')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value='m'>text</option>')
    .val('NEWval');
```

EDIT
I have a select val in my variable, i want to select only those in the select box and remove all others. *my purpose actually is to make the select box READONLY. when i tried with  'disabled' it is not reading the value from it*.

### EDIT 2

```
   var columns=[];
    var col=[];
    $('#' +id).find('td').each(function(index, cell){
        columns.push($(cell).text());
         col.push($(this).attr("class"));
    });

    var m = (col[2].match(/\d+/)); 
    // $('.selectBox').val(m) ; this was earlier to select the value that corresponds to "m"


 $('.selectBox option:contains(' + m + ')').show().siblings('option').hide();
 $('.selectBox').val(m);
```

But iam getting no changes in the select box.

Comment: not clear what you want to do

Comment: @Vohuman how to use `filter` , please give me a help here

Comment: is it clear @PranayRana

Comment: @SyamiliV, I would really like to help you if the scenario is clear, You may certainly want the select box to be disabled when any of the values is chosen? right? and you problem comes when you serialize the form and the value of this box doesn't appear at server side, right?

Comment: @Manoz : thanks manoz, but here iam not changing the select box. i mean i want a select box but from initially it should be able to show the select val which is retrieved from other page &in here in my variable `m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume if you have retrieved the value='3' from server side-

Then in your code-

```
    var value=3;//retrieved value

 $('.selectBox option[val="' + value + '"]')
    .prop('selected', true)
    .siblings()
    .attr('disabled',true);
```

Here is the demo-

http://jsfiddle.net/judnwcyf/6/

Comment: thanks Manoz .. can u please provide the older jsfiddle link where a select box value  retains only one value where others remain unselectable. { but i think at first we have to make a   ` on(change) event ` . can u help me make this from just before any event happens. }

Comment: And the above one is correct, but it just chooses the eaxact value. i just want this with an added feature of " not able to select the rest of them "

Comment: @SyamiliV, I have added and edited answer above, Please check link.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
var option = "ccc";

$('select option:contains(' + option + ')').show().siblings('option').hide();
$('select').val(option);
```

```js
var option = "ccc";

$('select option:contains(' + option + ')').show().siblings('option').hide();
$('select').val(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>select...</option>
  <option>aaa</option>
  <option>bbb</option>
  <option>ccc</option>
  <option>ddd</option>
</select>
```

As per your edit 2:

```
$('select option[value*="' + m + '"]').show().siblings('option').hide();
$('select').val(m);
```

Comment: this worked well... a small error in my side made it confused this much,.